# Why does %r{ around } my Regex break my gsub?

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

Rubocop pulled me over this afternoon for not wrapping my regex literals in %r{}. But it then proceeded to break my gsub. Why?

```
path = '/en/something'
# "/en/something"
locale = 'en'
# "en"
path.gsub(/\A\/#{locale}\/?/, '/')
# "/something" <---- Expected
path.gsub(%r{/\A\/#{locale}\/?/}, '/')
# "/en/something" <---- Unexpected
```

Comment: FYI – Rubocop has an [auto-correct option](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/usage/auto_correct.html) that can fix several offenses for you, including `%r{ ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby allows you to begin your regular expressions with `%r` followed by a delimiter of your choice. This is useful when the pattern you are describing contains a lot of forward-slash characters because these slashes do not need to be escaped in that syntax.

Therefore `/\A\/#{locale}\/?/` and `%r{/\A\/#{locale}\/?/}` are not equal, use `%r{\A/#{locale}/?}` instead.

```
r = /\A\/#{locale}\/?/

r == %r{/\A\/#{locale}\/?/}
#=> false
r == %r{\A/#{locale}/?}
#=> true
```

Comment: #facepalm -- I should have realised. I'm aware of other wrappers like %s and %w as well, d'oh!